# Assembly program jumping back to start?

Tags: assembly, arm

So this program is supposed to find the greatest number in array "TABLE". It does that pretty good. In the end, it has to write that highest number into variable "MAX" and it's index in "MAX_INDEX". The problem lies in the last 4 lines: When I arrive to str r2, [r0] , it just goes back to the first line, instead of simply writing the end value into variable MAX. Why?

```
                  .text

TABLE:           .hword 1, 5, -1, 8, -130, 1024, 10, 64, -80, 256 
TABLE_SIZE:      .byte 10
MAX:              
MAX_INDEX:        

                  .align 
                  .global __start

__start:          
                  adr r0, TABLE_SIZE
                  ldrb r5, [r0]
                  adr r0, TABLE

                  mov r1, #-1
                  mov r2, #0

READ:             ldrsh r4, [r0]
                  add r0, r0, #2
                  add r1, r1, #1
                  cmp r4, r2
                  bgt INDEX

                  cmp r1, r5
                  bne READ
                  cmp r1, r5
                  beq END

INDEX:            movs r2, r4
                  mov r3, r1

                  cmp r1, r5
                  bne READ

END:              adr r0, MAX
                  str r2, [r0]
                  adr r0, MAX_INDEX
                  str r3, [r0] 

__end:    b __end
```

Comment: How are you running / debugging this code?

Comment: You haven't reserved any space for `MAX` or `MAX_INDEX`, and neither of them are word-aligned. Also, you've placed them in the `.text` section, which isn't necessarily writeable.